# Which Type Of Heat Transfer?

Tags: radiation, thermal-conductivity

When are heating something up on the stove, is there a way it could show heat transfer through radiation?

Comment: You want the stove to provide a heat transfer calculation to you while you are heating something up?

Comment: @KXM9217 I do not believe stoves could be made to accurately discriminate the amounts of radiant, conductive, or convective heat transference.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about what you mean by the "something" being heated. Is the something you are referring to the food being cooked or the pan/pot being heated.

Answer (score 1):

New electric stoves (the ones with completely flat, glass-like cooking surfaces) heat pans by radiation and conduction. the radiant element under the stovetop heats the stovetop under the pan by radiative transfer and the hot stovetop then heats the pan by conduction.

Comment: Yes, but the food is heated (cooked) by conduction. I have asked the OP for clarification as what is meant by "something", i.e., the pot or the food.